# How can hide the encrypted partition in gui?

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption

I can encrypt my /dev/sdb4 with cryptsetup this way

```
sudo apt-get install cryptsetup
sudo umount  /dev/sdb4
sudo cryptsetup --verbose --verify-passphrase luksFormat /dev/sdb4
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb4  sec
sudo mkfs.ext3  /dev/mapper/sec
sudo mount /dev/mapper/sec  /mnt
```

People can't get the content in /dev/sdb4 without the key created.The partition can be shown in gui:

[image]

How can hide the encrypted partition in gui?

Comment: Just a nitpick, but why are you using ext3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a udev rule.  e.g. I use the following file (`/etc/udev/rules.d/95-hide-block-devices.rules`) to hide my mdadm devices and ZFS zvols from various GUI file selector dialogs:

```
KERNEL=="[mz]d*", ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1", ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}="1"
```

I only have one mdadm device these days (for /boot), and I definitely don't want that to be accidentally unmounted by clicking on the Eject icon.

I also have a lot of VMs on my desktop machine, all using ZFS zvols for storage - so this hides dozens of unwanted block device entries from `pcmanfm` (I use xfce4, not gnome) and from my file open & save dialogs.

In your case, you could use:

```
KERNEL=="sdb4", ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1", ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}="1"
```

You probably also want to hide the related device mapper block device, so add:

```
KERNEL=="dm-xxx", ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1", ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}="1"
```

(where `dm-xxx` is the device mapper name in /dev for your encrypted device. adjust to suit your system)

Remember to run `udevadm trigger` after creating or editing udev rules.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your distribution and Desktop environment, you can use the `gnome-disks`-utility and change the setting *show in user interface* of the partition's mount options.

Note: This does not hide the partition in all places, e.g. in different file-browsers. The partition is especially not hidden from cli-tools.